# Efficient way to convert large BSON data to GSON object

Tags: java, json, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

I have more than 10K json documents in a single MongoDB collection. I want to retrieve them & get as a google json document array. Following is my code snippet.

```
    FindIterable<Document> dbResult = db.getCollection("mycollection", Document.class).find(); 
        JsonArray result = new JsonArray();
        JsonObject jsonObject;
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

        for (Document doc : dbResult) {
             // --> toJson () is time/CPU consuming operation
            jsonObject = parser.parse(doc.toJson()).getAsJsonObject(); 
            result.add(jsonObject);
        }
```

**Issue**:

It takes too much memory and CPU cycles to get the GSON array. On profiling the code I found it toJSON() call which takes lot of CPU cycles.

I have following questions

1. The above code retrieves one BSON document & process it to GSON object. Is there any way I can retrieve multiple documents (say array instead of one document at a time).
2. How can I avoid toJSON call, I find it too slow specially when I have large number of json documents to retrieve. I would prefer a way to retrieve GSON object directly instead of first getting BSON --> to JSON string --> to GSON object.

Atul

Comment: You are doing it all wrong. Instead of building a whole array, simply output each parsed object to a "stream". If it's 10K documents the what would be the point of putting brackets `[]` around it anyway? That just means something reading it needs to slurp up just as much memory as you are expending on writing it. Take a look at what `mongoexport` and `mongoimport` does ( without the silly `--jsonArray` patch for "small" files ) and learn that "big parsers" generally use a different separator to delimit the objects.

Comment: thanks for the response, so you are suggesting to export the result(stream) into a file & parse the result to get the final data ? Won't I end up doing lot of file operations, assuming this is web service code, I have to serve multiple concurrent requests.

Comment: No. I'm "telling you" ( not suggesting ) that "parsing anything" is the completely incorrect approach. If you are writing 10K of records into JSON, then "write the JSON directly", and **at most** "parse" one document at a time into a JSON string format for that object. Insisting that "you need brackets" is complete nonsense, and you are pointed to tools that deliberately do not employ this practice. Learn from the example and follow what the "big tools" actually do.

Comment: Thanks Neil for response. Currently I am doing two stage parsing - one from BSON to JSON string & second is JSON string to GSON object. Are you suggesting me to remove second one or both?